# Camel - homemade "transactions"?

Tags: apache-camel

I am working on a data pipeline built on Camel and ActiveMQ. One route takes messages from a queue and exposes it via Netty on a socket for a C++ component to take them:

```
<from uri="activemq:queue:inqueue?concurrentConsumers=1"/
<camel:loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
  <camel:roundRobin/>
    <camel:to uri="netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:0?logicalName=comp#1&amp;sync=false"/>
    <camel:to uri="netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:0?logicalName=comp#2&amp;sync=false"/>
</camel:loadBalance>
```

I would like to be able to track message and keep track of status; if one of the C++ components does not respond with success with a certain threshold, I want to put the message back on the queue. I think about putting in a Camel process between the queue and Netty to keep track of this.

Is that a viable idea? How would this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about netty, but what you are looking for sounds like error handling.

you can add the following to your configure method to try it out.
You can also add retries and any other form of logging or error management if you like.

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("activemq:queue:errorQueue"));
```

Reference
http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html